# Is there a better Syntax for my active record select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, syntax

I got a user model method called "`has_separate_emails?`".

Normaly i do somethink like this:

```
Users.select{ |user| user.has_separate_emails? }
```

but i wrapped it up to this:

```
Users.select(&:has_separate_emails?)
```

the negate version would be:

```
Users.select{ |user| !user.has_separate_emails? }
```

And now the question, is there also a shorter/"wrapped" version for negated statements?

Comment: You know that you're pulling all the records out of the database when you do that, right? A better way would be to expression `has_separate_emails?` in terms that the database can understand so that you can let the database do the work.

Comment: Yes i know, but good point. Maybe i find a scope for that! Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
Users.reject(&:has_separate_emails?)
```